# Hibernate Criteria Api Subqueries

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am currently working on a project to transfer some legacy jdbc select statements over to using Hibernate and it's criteria api.

The two relevant table columns and the SQL query looks like:

```
-QUERIES-
primaryId

-QUERYDETAILS-
primaryId
linkedQueryId -> Foreign key references queries.primaryId
value1
value2

select * 
from queries q 
where q.primaryId not in (SELECT qd.linkedQueryId 
                          FROM querydetails qd 
                          WHERE (qd.value1 LIKE 'PROMPT%' 
                                 OR qd.value2 LIKE 'PROMPT%'));
```

My entity relationships look like:

```
@Table("queries")
public class QueryEntity{

    @Id
    @Column
    private Long primaryId;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = QueryDetailEntity.class, mappedBy = "query", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<QueryDetailEntities> queryDetails;

    //..getters/setters..

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "queryDetails")
public class QueryDetailEntity {
    @Id
    @Column
    private Long primaryId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = QueryEntity.class)
    private QueryEntity query;

@Column(name="value1")
private String value1;

@Column(name="value2")
private String value2;

    //..getters/setters..

}
```

I am attempting to utilize the criteria api in this way:

```
Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(QueryEntity.class);

DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(QueryDetailEntity.class);
LogicalExpression hasPrompt = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.ilike("value1", "PROMPT%"),
        Restrictions.ilike("value2", "PROMPT%"));
subQuery.add(hasPrompt);
Criterion subQueryCrit = Subqueries.notIn("queryDetails", subQuery);
crit.add(subQueryCrit);

List<QueryMainEntity> entities = (List<QueryMainEntity>) crit.list();
System.out.println("# of results = " + entities.size());
```

I am getting a NullPointerException on the crit.list() line that looks like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getProjectedTypes(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.createAndSetInnerQuery(SubqueryExpression.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.toSqlString(SubqueryExpression.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1687)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
```

Now, I think its pretty safe to say I'm using the Criteria Api/Detached Query Api incorrectly, but I'm not sure what the 'correct' way to do it is since the [Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries) only briefly cover criteria api subqueries.

I realize  this is a pretty long question, but I figure its appear to put it all the relevant aspects of the question (query I'm attempting to represent via Criteria API, tables, entities).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
DetachedCriteria d = DetachedCriteria.forClass(QueryDetailEntity.class, "qd");
d.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("qd.query")));
d.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("qd.value1", "PROMPT%"), Restrictions.like("qd.value2", "PROMPT%")));

criteria = session.createCriteria(QueryEntity.class, "q");
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("q.primaryId", d));
criteria.list();
```

The use of the following are property names, not column names:

```
qd.query
qd.value1
qd.value2
q.primaryId
```

As a side note, if this is not a dynamically generated query, have you given thought to using HQL instead?

Comment: I came to the same (or similiar, rather) solution utilizing NOT EXISTS type subquery.  The part that was tripping me up was the setting up of the Projection out of the subquery.  Somewhat unrelated to this question, but I was having issues after I had come to the this solution because the child table (querydetails) was being outerjoined on bringing back more records than I actually expected. To fix this, I altered the fetch strategy for QueryDetailEntities#queryDetails to have the annotation @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)