# Pagination in Hibernate with joined tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pagination

There are a lot of questions about it but I couldn't find a concrete answer.
I'm new to Hibernate and trying to implement pagination.
Let's say I have two entities: Parent and Child which are defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Parents")
public class Parent{

   @Id
   @Column(name="id", length=255)
   private String id;

   @Column(name="name", length=255)
   protected String name;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinTable(name="parents_children", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="parent_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="child_id"))
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   protected List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="children")
public class Child {

   @Id
   @Column(name="id", length=255)
   protected String id;

   @Column(name="name", length=255)
   protected String name;


  }
```

Each property also has getter and setter as required.

I want to get the **first page** of **Parents** **ordered by name**, where **each page is 10 results**.

So I started from:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Parent.class, "p");
    c.createAlias("q.children", "ch"); 
    c.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    c.addOrder(Order.desc("name"));
    c.setMaxResults(10);
    c.setFirstResult(0);
    List<Parent> result = c.list();
    session.close();
```

This code doesn't work as expected because the setMaxResults is performed on the joined table and not on the parents list (as I want it to be).

My question is what should be the query to get paging on the Parents list and not on the joined table?

Answer (score 1):

Pagination does not work with joined collections because it counts all the rows that have satisfied the `where` predicate (Hibernate has nothing to do with this, it is how databases work, for example [Oracle `rownum`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)).

The usual way to overcome this is to use subqueries, so that `rownum` (or the equivalent in the database used) is applied to the selected rows of only one table (or joined tables which are in to-one relationships).

In HQL:

```
select p from Parent p were p in (select c.parent from Child c where ...)
```

The [criteria equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902898/hibernate-criteria-api-subqueries) can be built in a similar way.

Comment: Could you please provide the most efficient sql query for pagination (I'm using mysql)?

Comment: Based on what you provided in the question (page through parents that have children), the most efficient query should be exactly what I provided in the answer: `select p from Parent p were p in (select c.parent from Child c)`.

Answer (score 0):

you have used `c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)` for find distinct `Parent` which is executing after data come from database.after comment this line you will get the correct output but parrent are duplicated.

After evaluation of your problem i found a link on stackoverflow which related to your problem. It's will help you.you to following link .
[Stackoverflow Criteria Pagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577219/pagination-issue-while-join-in-hibernate-criteria)